# How to replace every different char with another given char

Tags: c#, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I need to replace every 'a' char with 'b' char, every 'b' char with 'c' char and so on. I've tried to make this with if but code is very very long for every char. Exists a method how mo make this without if or switch or something like that?

```
        char[] chars = new char[inputString.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputString[i] == 'a')
                chars[i] = 'b';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'b')
                chars[i] = 'c';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'c')
                chars[i] = 'd';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'd')
                chars[i] = 'e';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'e')
                chars[i] = 'f';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'f')
                chars[i] = 'g';
            else if (inputString[i] == 'g')
                chars[i] = 'h';
            else
            {
                chars[i] = inputString[i];
            }
        }
        string outputString = new string(chars);
```

This is how i need to replace:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
Z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a


0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Example: 
string: TEXTcsharp#2367 
result: SDWSdtibsq#7632

Comment: Possible consider a `Dictionary<char, char>` for "key maps to value"?

Comment: What do you want to happen with 'z'? What about numbers and punctuation? And 'A' to 'Z'?

Comment: Cast it to `int` +1 and back to `char`?

Comment: Side note: Take utmost caution when attempting these kind of multiple replacements so that your program logic doesn't accidentally get into a situation where a replacment replaces a prior replacement (unless for whatever strange reason that would be desired). For example, say you have two replacement rules `o`->`u` and `u`->`i`. Applying these two rules in a sequential/iterative manner to the word "shot" might not yield "shut" but rather "sh*t" if you don't pay attention to these things...

Comment: @elgonzo "pock" would have been a better choice, some people for whom English is not their first language might wonder where the asterisk came from.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, i think most people will get the word i self-censored there (i hope). To read anything here on StackOverflow, basic English reading comprehension skills are required anyway... ;-)

Comment: Why not using replace with a temp var?

Comment: @AndrewMorton To complete the question this is a table and an example about my exercise i will edit the post

Comment: @Yamato As the question has been marked as a duplicate, no-one can add another answer. I suggest that you look at the "other way" part of [Rufus L's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859726/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast it to `int` and add 1:

```
char[] chars = new char[inputString.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
{
    chars[i] = (char)(inputString[i] + 1);
}
string outputString = new string(chars);
```

This works, because every `char` has a [numeric representation](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). However you probably need some extra logic for `z` or so (depending if you want to constraint the values to the alphabet).

Also since this is tagged with [crypt](/questions/tagged/crypt): Use [Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model) if you want to do encryption, instead of rolling your own. Even security experts have problems with creating a secure one.

Comment: Thank you. I used crypt tag because i have an exercise that tells me to make a "crypt" algorithm for encrypt a string.

Comment: If it's an exercise, than probably your teacher want's you to to some replacement, as above. **But disclaimer** In reality **never never ever** do this, and use battle tested Cryptography Libraries. *(That's the part I hate about our schools. Nothing wrong with some exercise, but calling this encryption is crazy)*

Comment: You are right !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher (which is what question is about) is considered encryption and generally part of cryptography field... Note that [tag:crypt] (which absolutely does not apply to this question) is not about [tag:cryptography] (which I think would be perfectly fine).

Comment: [encryption is the process of encoding a message or information in such a way that **only authorized parties can access it**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). I can't see this applied in this example. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt :) so RSA is not encryption by that definition as it is theoretically possible to find the key and hence information is available to anyone anyway... or RSA is not encryption because keys can be too small and be actually broken in practice... I understand what you trying to recommend... just disagree with narrowing down definition of "encryption" to "uses strong crypto  algorithms"

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
    string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string bcd = new string(abc.Select(x => x == 'z' ? 'a' : (char)(x + 1)).ToArray());
```